# How to expand map in a grid in C#?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

xaml

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">    
<maps:Map x:Name="mapWithMyLocation" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1,0,0,443" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="233" Width="479" ZoomLevel="10"/>
    <Grid Margin="0,0,0,77" Grid.Row="1" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Height="366" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <phone:LongListSelector x:Name="closestBusList" ItemsSource="{Binding KioskList}" SelectionChanged="closestBusList_SelectionChanged_1" Height="366" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                 <DataTemplate>
                     <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Opacity="0.5" Background="WhiteSmoke">
                         <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#0145A6" FontSize="14" x:Name="owner" Text="{Binding owner}"></TextBlock>
                         <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#038edf" FontSize="12" x:Name="addres" Text="{Binding address}"></TextBlock>
                     </StackPanel>
                 </DataTemplate>
             </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
         </phone:LongListSelector>
     </Grid>
</Grid>
```

cs

```
private void expand_btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    double height = this.mapWithMyLocation.Height;
    double from, to;

    // animate from 150 to 800, or vice versa
    if (height == 233)
    {
        from = 233;
        to = 800;
        closestBusList.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
    else
    {
        from = 800;
        to = 233;
        closestBusList.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }

    Storyboard sb = new System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard();
    DoubleAnimation fillHeightAnimation = new System.Windows.Media.Animation.DoubleAnimation();
    fillHeightAnimation.From = from;
    fillHeightAnimation.To = to;
    fillHeightAnimation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.3));

    Storyboard.SetTarget(fillHeightAnimation, this.mapWithMyLocation);
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(fillHeightAnimation, new PropertyPath("Height"));

    sb.Children.Add(fillHeightAnimation);
    sb.Begin();

}
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors OR it's not working at all?

Comment: No error, location in map is like going down but the height of the map is not changing. Is it because it is in the grid and sharing spot with listselector?

Comment: Most likely because VerticalAlignment is set to Bottom. Try to get rid of that and see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding three row definitions and adding the map inside grid, the problem solved.